# cloudsearch API java upload

Tags: java, api, upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

'Hello ! I would like to upload datas on a already created cloudsearch domain.
I already process the datas by using a mapreduce job with hadoop to create a string in the JSON format.

I can't find how to upload a String directly to Amazon Cloud Search to get the data into the search domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You post the documents to the documents search endpoints. (search endpoints can be found in the AWS console dashboard for your domain).

You can do this using command line tools Amazon provides, or using their java API, use curl, or just write code in your favorite language to post. There's also boto, which is a python library for aws.

Details here http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/faqs/#How_do_I_upload_documents_to_my_search_domain

Comment: Hi, how can i do this using java API. Any sample code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to insert data into Cloud Search you need to use Document End point of Cloud Search given to you by AWS.

It needs to be followed by the API version as below:

https://doc-xxxxx.zzzz.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/documents/batch

Bare in mind currently AWS batch size 5 MB maximum when uploading documents via Java.